# When both LAN card 1 and wifi adaptor are enabled, internet connection doesn't work

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

Problem: if for some reason router 1 does not have internet, i turn on WIFI adaptor for hotspot. When both LAN card 1 and wifi adaptor are enabled, internet connection doesn't work. But when I disable LAN card 1, internet works from wifi adaptor but I loose LAN to other PCs and NAS. How can I fix this?

Here's my setup:

LAN card 1 (Built-in) ISP Cable Modem >>> Router 1 >>> LAN 1 (using DHCP provided by the Router - full control) 
IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.201 IPv4 
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0 IPv4 
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1 
* Router 1 - this is for internet access and all other LAN computers and NAS devices etc.

LAN card 2 (wifi adaptor) - any working wifi-hotspot as ISP >>> Wireless Network Connection (using DHCP provided by the hotspot - so cannot change anything here ) 
IPv4 Address: 192.168.43.44 
IPv4 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0 
IPv4 Default Gateway: 192.168.43.1

Comment: your question doesnt make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution mentioned in the thread from [this link](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2234484/lan-cards-internet-lan.html) can help you , as his use case was just about making one LAN usage permanently for intranet and other for internet. But you might get some ideas for your usage.

Comment: Thanks, but it works for 2 different routers setup.
My case is different